# MySQL 8: trying to alter two TIMESTAMP tables from NOT NULL to NULL and from '0000-00-00 00:00:00' to NULL as default value

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `acquisition` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `received` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `parsed` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I'm trying to change a couple of columns to nullable and assign them `NULL` as default value.

```
ALTER TABLE acquisition MODIFY COLUMN received TIMESTAMP  NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE acquisition MODIFY COLUMN parsed TIMESTAMP  NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

I get this:

`#1067 - Invalid default value for 'parsed'`

so looks like the first one is being executed but not the second one.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an effect of current `SESSION sql_mode` server setting. You must clear it before your actions and restore after.

### DEMO

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
SET @old_sql_mode = @@sql_mode;
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';
```

| @@sql_mode |
| --- |
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |

```
CREATE TABLE `acquisition` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `received` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `parsed` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
SHOW CREATE TABLE acquisition;
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| acquisition | CREATE TABLE `acquisition` ( `id` int NOT NULL, `received` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `parsed` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

```
INSERT INTO acquisition VALUES 
(1, NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY, NOW() - INTERVAL 4 DAY),
(2, NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY, DEFAULT),
(3, DEFAULT, NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY),
(4, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
SELECT * FROM acquisition;
```

| id | received | parsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-20 13:07:12 | 2023-01-21 13:07:12 |
| 2 | 2023-01-22 13:07:12 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2023-01-23 13:07:12 |
| 4 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |

```
ALTER TABLE acquisition MODIFY COLUMN received TIMESTAMP  NULL DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE acquisition MODIFY COLUMN parsed TIMESTAMP  NULL DEFAULT NULL;
SHOW CREATE TABLE acquisition;
SELECT * FROM acquisition;
UPDATE acquisition
SET received = NULLIF(received, '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
    parsed = NULLIF(parsed, '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
SET SESSION sql_mode = @old_sql_mode;
SELECT * FROM acquisition;
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| acquisition | CREATE TABLE `acquisition` ( `id` int NOT NULL, `received` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, `parsed` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

| id | received | parsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-20 13:07:12 | 2023-01-21 13:07:12 |
| 2 | 2023-01-22 13:07:12 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 2023-01-23 13:07:12 |
| 4 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |

| id | received | parsed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-20 13:07:12 | 2023-01-21 13:07:12 |
| 2 | 2023-01-22 13:07:12 | *null* |
| 3 | *null* | 2023-01-23 13:07:12 |
| 4 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xkL2QEeQ)